# how to create variable property in protocol where as {get set} for one class and {get} for another class

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var mustBeSettable: String { get set }
}

class Stage1: SomeProtocol {
    //Here "mustBeSettable" should be {get set}
}

class Stage2: SomeProtocol {
    //Here "mustBeSettable" should be {get} only
}
```

> in Stage1 class I need access for "mustBeSettable" as {get set}, where as in Stage2 class "mustBeSettable" should be {get} only. but same property I need to use in both classes.

Comment: Then you can't always set `mustBeSettable`? If you have a variable `x` of type `SomeProtocol`. What do you expect to happen when you do `x.mustBeSettable = "something"` when `x` is an instance of `Stage2`?

Comment: create two protocols - one that only requires `{ get }`, and the other that inherits from the first, and also requires `{ get set }`... or, to avoid a potential X-Y problem - explain what you're actually trying to achieve

Comment: Your design is wrong. protocol is like a contract. If the property setter is not always required (optional) you need to remove `set` from your protocol declaration `var mustBeSettable: String { get }` btw your property naming doesn't make any sense as you've already said that it might not be settable.

Answer (score 0):

The possible solution is to do it in reverse order, make originally read-only at protocol level (otherwise it would not be possible to fulfil protocol requirements):

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var mustBeSettable: String { get }
}

class Stage1: SomeProtocol {
    var mustBeSettable: String      // read-write
    
    init(_ value: String) {
        mustBeSettable = value
    }
}

class Stage2: SomeProtocol {
    let mustBeSettable: String     // read-only

    init(_ value: String) {
        mustBeSettable = value
    }
}
```